# Using viewPager with fragments android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

I have already tried a lot of tutorials but i am kind of new on android, so here's my problem. I need a Viewpager inside a fragment of Navigation Drawer.

I have a drawer layout with the MainActivity and fragment A , B , C and D . 

On fragment C I have my layout , like textViews, imageViews and I need to add a viewPager like on iOS devices.
The problem is every tutorial, and questions answered here, says to start the PageAdapter on the Activity , but I need to use it on the Fragment because it's where I have the information to populate the information of the C fragment.

The view pager that should appear, only contains a textView that is populated with a webservice request where I get the message to put on the textView, that's why i need this on the Fragment C.

 So here is my pageAdapter:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private String message;

public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm , String message) {
    super(fm);
    this.message = message;

}

/**
 * Get fragment corresponding to a specific position. This will be used to populate the
 * contents of the view pager
 *
 * @param position Position to fetch fragment for.
 * @return Fragment for specified position.
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

    Fragment fragment = new PageVestiarioFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("message", message);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Get number of pages the should render.
 *
 * @return Number of fragments to be rendered as pages.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}
}
```

And this is my pageViewer item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/pageViewLayout"
tools:context="com.example.mobirama.golaco.VestiarioFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mensagem recebida via rest"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_green" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my fragment C layout, as long as there is too much information i'll put just the piece where there is the pageview (this is inside a relativeLayout)

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/messages_ScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

             </RelativeLayout>

         </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Just a piece of where I set the information

```
 for (Integer i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            if (messages[i] != null) {
                items.add(messages[i]);
                mAdapter = new PageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager() , messages[i].getMessage());
                pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }
```

The problem is android studio shows this message : android.support.v4.app.fragmentmanager does not match with android.support.app.fragmentmanager

I tried to change to support v13 but didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Take a look to this app: https://github.com/Dahnark/Material-Design-Tabs, it is an app to show tabs inside a fragment. You can add the FrameLayout inside of your drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Which compatibility level are you targeting? You need to make everything match:

- FragmentPagerAdapter
- your Fragment objects, especially the fragment C

From your XML (  )I can see you are targeting v4 so you might want to change everything to v4.

Comment: when everything is with v4 i have the problem of compability : android.support.v4.app.fragmentmanager does not match with android.support.app.fragmentmanager

Comment: Where is this error happening? and where is the instance of android.support.app.fragmentmanager? If your fragment calling getChildFragmentManager() is an instance of Fragment from the v4 support library is should work fine.

Comment: The problem of compability is solved i am using v13 but it still doesn't shows the layout